# Simulate only one vehicle using Veins in omnet++

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm new to veins although I've already simulated a simple example in omnet++. I want to know how simulate only one vehicle based simulation. I' want to communicate the vehicle with nearby pedestrians.

**Note:** I've been already read and understand the installation tutorial (http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/). I want to build my network from scratch using Veins as reference project in omnet++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default (and in the Veins tutorial simulation), vehicles are created by SUMO. If you want to create fewer (or more) vehicles, you will need to modify the SUMO simulation.

Comment: Thank you, sir, it's done. Now I want to replace RSU with a node based router. Any direction or procedure that how can i replace the RSU with a router to perform my test-bed.
Thank you very much for your reply, really I'm stuck here.

Comment: **Note:** I'm referencing the project of which I want to use base node by using omnet++

Comment: It’s unlikely that other people will find your second question here. I’d suggest to open a new one

Comment: OK. sir, I have asked in this post.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60991015/replace-rsu-with-a-node-based-router-in-veins