# Replace RSU with a node based router in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I want to replace RSU with a node based router. Any direction or procedure that how can i replace the RSU with a router to perform my test-bed. Thank you very much for your help, really I'm stuck here.
**Note:** I'm doing the project referencing of which project I want to use node based rputer by using omnet++.

Answer (score 0):

Veins_INET makes it possible to use Veins as a mobility model in INET.

If your implementation of a wireless router is based on the network stack of INET, node mobility of moving vehicles will be accurately represented in your simulation.